# Plotting points on Google map while travelling and create route using points

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-markers

Which Google API is used to plot points in Google map as travelling with the help of markers?

Comment: Add some code which you have tried or try reading this [GoogleMapsAPI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation)

Comment: Show us what you have done yet.